# Get the client_id and client_secret dinamically in django with the social_oauth2 authentication

Tags: python, django, oauth

I want to authenticate the users with Oauth but in the request to get the tokens I have to put the client_id and client_secret hardcoded, is there a better form to have dynamically these credentials, or just I have two credentials for all the users?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So all requests to the same auth provider will have the same `client_id` and `client_secret` (unless there is a reason why they dont do this) think of these as usernames and passwords to the authentication service. To any normal service you wouldnt tend to have multiple keys.

You can store these credentials in the django settings which means you can have different client_id/secret for each environment. It will also give you the ability to change the secrets easier (and not have to commit them into source control).

Social auth itself will have support for multiple client_id and client_secret pairs. These will be depenedant on the providers which you have enabled and it will be configurable in the settings. For example:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY = 'foobar'
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET = 'bazqux'

# or

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_KEY = 'foobar'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET = 'bazqux'
```

These keys will automatically be used in each of the auth providers you have enabled in settings.

The [docs on django social auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/settings.html#configuration) have some examples of this.

Comment: So I can Have the same client_id and client_secret for login with a custom email and have other client_id and client_secret for login with the Gmail API?